# Error in y(sort(x), ...) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Tags: r

I am trying to perform KS.test on each column of a given matrix. but I get an error as it is shown in the title. What I did is as follows:

```
url <- 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/052e50e7e777849449b3/raw/data_example.txt'
 library(RCurl)
 x <- getURL(url, ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)

 df1 <- read.delim(textConnection(x),header=TRUE, row.names=1, 
            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 dim(df1)
 #[1] 507 990

 lst <- Map(function(x,y,z) setNames(data.frame(y,x)[order(-x),], 
            c('name', z)), df1, list(rownames(df1)), names(df1))

res <- do.call(cbind,lst)
 row.names(res) <- NULL
```

to calculate KS.test I perform the following command

```
f <- function(res) unlist(ks.test(res,"punif")[1:2])
 apply(res[,seq(1,length(res),by=2)],2,f)
```

The error is **Error in y(sort(x), ...) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function**

Comment: I remember this code:-)

Comment: @akrun this is your own code akrun, I accepted your solution however, does not lead me to what I am looking for. I just did not make it complicated, to address there or here! simply I asked what could be the problem but feel free to edit my question if you like to

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `seq(2,length(res), by=2)` as the 1,3,5, etc. columns are the names columns, or just `apply(res[,c(FALSE, TRUE)], 2, f)`

Comment: @akrun May I ask a question? how can you write program like this ? i am killing myself but I have got no where !!!!! if you are somewhere I can chat or ask , don't hesitate to share your email or anything else !

Comment: @akrun can you please modify the function as an answer and make it in a way to save the result in a file named for example Results so that I will accept your solution :-)

Comment: It is only based on experience/practice.  My friend, I am no different than you or any other person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
res1 <- t(apply(res[,seq(2,length(res),by=2)],2,f))
row.names(res1) <- NULL #if you don't need the row names
head(res1,2)
#     statistic.D p.value
#[1,]   0.8010560       0
#[2,]   0.7025389       0
```

Or

```
res1 <- t(apply(res[,c(FALSE, TRUE)], 2, f))
```

as the 1st, 3rd, 5th,..etc column are non-numeric...

Comment: Imagine I use this, still my result is not saved in a file f <- function(res) unlist(ks.test(res,"punif")[1:2])
 apply(res[,seq(2,length(res),by=2)],2,f)

Comment: @Nemo I will check, didn't run it.

Comment: @Nemo If I run the code `res1 <- apply(res[,c(FALSE, TRUE)], 2, f)`.  I get `2x990` matrix.  I didn't understand your comment

Comment: sorry for late acceptance, I was out, now I checked and I found I made somewhere mistake but your solution is surely right !.